Why is Webgl canvas effected by CSS background?
When I set my body element of background #000, and the circle seems great:
Figure A
However, with unset or #fff background, the color of the edge of this circle seems like calculated with white and goes into yellow.
Figure B
Despite of setting white to the canvas with gl.clearColor and gl.clear, colors of the circle do not change.
Additionally, expected result is be like: The result can be done with both gl.clearColor(1,1,1,1) and CSS background: #000.
Figure C
With my JS:
let cv = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.append(cv);
[ cv.width, cv.height ] = [50, 50];
let gl = cv.getContext("webgl");

function createProgram() {
    function initShader(ty, src) {
        let shader = gl.createShader(ty);
        gl.shaderSource(shader, src);
        gl.compileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }

    let prog = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(prog, initShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vs));
    gl.attachShader(prog, initShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fs));
    gl.linkProgram(prog);
    gl.useProgram(prog);
    return prog;
}

const vs = `
attribute vec4 a_pos;
attribute float a_size;
void main() {
    gl_Position = a_pos;
    gl_PointSize = a_size;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
varying float v_alpha;

float alpha() {
    return 1. - distance(gl_PointCoord, vec2(.5, .5)) * 2.;
}
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.0, alpha());
}
`;

const prog = createProgram();

const a_pos = gl.getAttribLocation(prog, "a_pos");
const a_size = gl.getAttribLocation(prog, "a_size");

gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

gl.vertexAttrib2f(a_pos, 0, 0);
gl.vertexAttrib1f(a_size, 50);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

and HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>gl</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #000;
        }
        canvas {
            transform: scale(16);
            transform-origin: 0 0;
            image-rendering: pixelated;
            /* background-color: #fff; */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

I think this circle should not be effected by the CSS background, and I need to know if there is any configuration missed for my program.
Though I am able to just set the background #000 and clear the canvas with #fff to get the right result, but I'm now confused about that. Thanks for your patience.

I think the color doesn't change. It's just how human eyes work


let cv = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.append(cv);
[cv.width, cv.height] = [50, 50];
let gl = cv.getContext("webgl");

function createProgram() {
  function initShader(ty, src) {
    let shader = gl.createShader(ty);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, src);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    return shader;
  }

  let prog = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(prog, initShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vs));
  gl.attachShader(prog, initShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fs));
  gl.linkProgram(prog);
  gl.useProgram(prog);
  return prog;
}

const vs = `
attribute vec4 a_pos;
attribute float a_size;
void main() {
    gl_Position = a_pos;
    gl_PointSize = a_size;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
varying float v_alpha;

float alpha() {
    return 1. - distance(gl_PointCoord, vec2(.5, .5)) * 2.;
}
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.0, alpha());
}
`;

const prog = createProgram();

const a_pos = gl.getAttribLocation(prog, "a_pos");
const a_size = gl.getAttribLocation(prog, "a_size");

gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

gl.vertexAttrib2f(a_pos, 0, 0);
gl.vertexAttrib1f(a_size, 50);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

canvas {
  transform: scale(16);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  animation: anim 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  to {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
}




Actually, you may add
gl.clearColor(1,1,1,1); gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
before drawing, and with your animation, the circle will change its color with the white background.
